# How many hours needed for them to meet in the starting point?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Andrew and Jim start to run in circular path from the same point, if Andrew can complete $6$ cycles per hour, and Jim can complete $8$ cycles per hour, how many hours are needed for them to meet at the starting point?

My answer is to find $L.C.M (6,8)=24$

but this answer seems to be for cycles  i.e , they will meet each other after $24$ cycle , but the problem is about number of hours not cycles .

What is the right answer?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you state the two cases please

Comment: Clearly they will meat at the starting point after one hour.

Comment: After *whose* 24 cycles?

Comment: @Ross Millikan why is that?

Comment: Because Andrew will have done six cycles and Jim eight.

Comment: Lowest common multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Answer

They will meet after 30 minutes, or one half hour. We can rephrase our information in the following way.

- Andrew completes six cycles per hour $\Rightarrow$ one cycle every 10 minutes.
- Jim completely eight cycles per hours $\Rightarrow$ one cycle every 7.5 minutes.

Our question is to find out the shortest time after Andrew and Jim begin running. Let's follow Jim around the track since he is the fastest, and every time he reaches the starting point, we'll try to find Andrew.

- After 7.5 minutes, Andrew is still a quarter of the cycle away from reaching the starting point.
- After 15 minutes, Andrew is half the cycle away.
- After 22.5 minutes, Andrew is three quarters away.
- After 30 minutes, Jim and Andrew meet! Jim ran four cycles total, where Andrew ran three.

### The Generalization

Edit: To be more general, suppose that Andrew runs a cycle in $\frac{1}{x}$ hours, and Jim runs a cycle in $\frac{1}{y}$ hours. We want to find integers $a,b$ such that $\frac{a}{x} = \frac{b}{y}$ is minimal. This is equivalent to $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{x}{y}$ to be minimal, which means reducing the fraction $\frac{x}{y}$ into lowest terms by dividing both $x$ and $y$ by $\gcd(x,y)$. Denote this by $\frac{x'}{y'}$. Then the amount of time before Andrew and Jim meet is $\frac{x'}{x}$ or $\frac{y'}{y}$.

However, we note $x' = \frac{x}{\gcd(x,y)}$, so they meet in $\frac{1}{\gcd(x,y)}$ hours.

### Examples

In the asker's example, we have that $\gcd(6,8)=2$, so they meet in $\frac{1}{2}$ hours. In @fleablood's example, we have that $\gcd(26,36) = 2$, so they meet in $\frac{1}{2}$ hours.

Comment: What if it had been more complicated  Jim runs 36 laps an hour and Alan runs 26 in an hour. Jim runs a lap in 1 minute 40 seconds and 2.307 minutes.  you'll have to do 18 calculations before you get them to meet.

Comment: I edited my question to address the general case!

Answer (score 1):

Figure out the time it takes each to run *one* cycle.  Andrew $1/6$ and Jim $1/8$ and find the least common integer multiple of $1/6$ and $1/8$.  I.e. what is the smallest value of $k$ where $k= \frac m6 = \frac n8$ for positive integers $m,n$.

i.e.  $48k = 8m = 6n = lcm(6,8) = 24$ so $k = \frac 12$ and Andrew has run 3 laps and Jim has run 4 laps.

In general the least common integer multiple of $a/b$ and $c/d$ will be the $\frac {lcm(ad,bc)}{bd}$.  (I think, someone might want to verify that.)

...... or .......

Consider $\gcd(8,6) = 2$.  That means there is some  $2*k= 8$ and $k=8/2 = 4$ which means in half an hour Jim will have run $4$ laps.  $2*m = 6$ and $m = 6/2 =3$ so in half an hour, Andrew would have ran $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Andrew completes a cycle in $\frac 16$ hour and Jim in $\frac 18$ hour.  If Andrew does $A$ cycles, he takes $\frac A6$ hours.  If Jim does $J$ cycles, he takes $\frac J8$ hours.  You need to find the smallest whole numbers $A,J$ that permit $\frac A6=\frac J8$